# How to implement css ensureInjected() in an UML sequence diagram?

Tags: gwt, uml

How could I implement the following code in UML sequence diagram ?

MyObject.getClientBundle().getCss().ensureInjected();

The css contains settings for the browser

```
@if user.agent safari {
    body {
 background-image: literal('-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(rgb(46, 54, 60)))');
    }
   }
```

Please help.

---

Okay thanks, but what should I do with the ensureInjected()? 
Should I create an browser-object? 
something like this

[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

While calls MyObject:entity getClientBundle() a call is placed for getCss(). While this is executed it calls ensureInjected() and returns. All other returns happen after that one after the other. (It is hard to explain without a picture wich i cant create at the moment).